# When will a pointed category / arrow category be cartesian closed / a model category if the base category is cartesian closed / a model category?

Tags: reference-request, category-theory

For a category $\mathcal{C}$ with terminal object we have some construction on it :

- define the pointed category to be $*\downarrow \text{Id}$ the coslice category relative to the terminal object ;
- and we have the arrow category $\text{Id}\downarrow\text{Id}$ ;
- furthermore, we define the category of pairs to be the subcategory of the arrow category where the objects are not morphism pairs, but monomorphism pairs (or regular monomorphism?).

If $\mathcal{C}$ is cartesian closed, under what condition will the three previous categories be cartesian closed with *smash product* and *map of pairs*? Same question if $\mathcal{C}$ is a model category. Any reference?

For $f\colon A\to X$ and $g\colon B\to Y$,

- smash product:

  - pushout of $\mathrm{id}\times f\colon A\times B \to A\times Y$ and $g\times \mathrm{id}\colon A\times B\to X\times B$ denoted by $(X, A)\otimes (Y, B)$
  - the map $(X, A)\otimes (Y, B)\to X\times Y$
- map of pairs:

  - because the functor $(-)^A$ is continuous, we have $g'\colon B^A\to Y^A$
  - composing $\mathrm{id}\times f\colon Y^X\times A\to Y^X\times X$ and the evaluation map $\epsilon\colon Y^X\times X\to Y$ we have a function $Y^X\times A\to Y$ then we have induced a function $f'\colon Y^X\to Y^A$
  - we have the pullback of the two functions $f'$ and $g'$ denoted by $(Y, B)^{(X, A)}$
  - the map $B^X\to (Y, B)^{(X, A)}$

We know the cartesian closed question is true for pointed category of compactly generated weak Hausdorff space.

If $\mathcal{C}$ is a model category we know the slice category and coslice category is a model category.

(These are results from Peter May's *Concise Algebraic Topology* and *More Concise Algebraic Topology*.)

To what extend can we generalise these results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the answers, in no particular order:

- Categories with a zero object are cartesian closed if and only if they are trivial – see e.g. [here](https://mathoverflow.net/a/136480/11640). In particular, the category of pointed objects is almost never cartesian closed.
- The smash product is *not* the cartesian product in the category of pointed objects. However, under good conditions, it is a symmetric monoidal product and we get a symmetric monoidal closed category.
- The category of arrows is cartesian closed if the original category is cartesian closed and has finite limits.
- The category of arrows has a Reedy model structure if the original category has a model structure – see e.g. [Hovey, *Model categories*, §5.2] or [Hirschhorn, *Model categories and their localizations*, Ch. 15].
- Under good conditions, the category of pairs will be a reflective subcategory of the category of arrows; and if the reflector preserves finite products, then the category of pairs will be cartesian closed (if the category of arrows is cartesian closed).

I don't know if the category of pairs inherits a model structure. Sometimes model structures can be transferred across adjunctions, sometimes not.

Comment: any reference about "under good conditions" for pointed category?

Comment: I think it suffices to have a cartesian closed category with equalisers and reflexive coequalisers. See the discussion [here](http://nforum.mathforge.org/discussion/5675/pointed-object/).

Comment: ... and also finite coproducts, of course.

Comment: A very general consideration of the smash products appears in my thesis (which I can link here in a couple of weeks, perhaps).

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Please do post the link here when available, thanks!